# Simplifying a laurent series involving inverse squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, laurent-series

If I write
$$
H(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(x+k)^2} + \ldots
$$
I can see that finding $H(1)$ amounts to the Basel problem, which makes me a bit pessimistic, but...

Is there any chance that $H$ has some "nice" representation that doesn't directly involve an infinite sum (even if some constant like $\zeta(2)$ appears)?

It's been nearly a half-century since I studied complex variables, and I wasn't great at it even back then, alas.

Perhaps I should also mention the more general problem from which I extracted this one, because it may actually be simpler. I'd like to sum up
$$
L(x) =  \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} +  \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\ldots + \frac{1}{(2+x)^2} + \frac{1}{(2-x)^2} + \ldots
$$

Comment: note that the partial fraction decomposition of of $\pi^2/\sin^2  \pi z$ is $\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z}\frac{1}{(z+k)^2}$ while the asymmetric guy with only nonnegative numbers is (more or less) $\psi'$ where $\psi =\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}$

Comment: Wolfram says that $H$ is actually exactly a series for $\psi'$. I'll fiddle a little to massage that into a series for $L$.